# Getting an error in android studio when using selenium. can any one please suggest how can I resolve this issue?

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver

> Error:Gradle: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException:
>   Error while dexing com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMapKeySet.class
>
> Error:Gradle: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba
>   (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
>
> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException:
> >     com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to
> >     process
> >     C:******files2.1\com.google.guava\guava\23.0\c947004bb13d18182be60077ade044099e4f26f1\guava-23.0.jar

Comment: Please update the android sdk version to api level 24 minimum hope this will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update the android sdk version to api level 24 minimum hope this will help